# Local IP of NIC - Light Weight Filter Driver

Tags: driver, ndis, filter-driver

How do we retrieve the Local Ip address set of the NIC in NDIS 6. I will be doing some IP header modifications on the received Ethernet Frames, so will be looking for local ip of NIC card that my Filter Attached to.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally a layering violation for an NDIS LWF driver (which operates at layer 2 of the OSI stack) to get involved with IP addresses (which are at layer 3 of the OSI stack).

If you have a very good reason do to this, you can query GetUnicastIpAddressTable.  Keep in mind that a NIC may not have any IP address (e.g., it's used for non-IP protocols).  Or it may carry IP traffic, but the OS doesn't know about any IP address (e.g., a guest VM is sending IP traffic through the host's NIC, but only the guest really knows the IP address).

In other words, NICs don't really *have* IP addresses.  At best, you can say that the NIC may be associated with an IP interface which has some number of IP addresses.

Comment: I will be setting IP address for adapter manually, instead of "Obtain an IP address automatically" on the IPv4 properties. When the driver attached to the adatper that set the ip, I need to retrive the ip and use it in my driver. As you suggested I have used GetUnicastIpAddressTable to but I am not getting the Ip address that corresponds to the adapter that I attach. I have two adapters which I set ip to 10.135.24.1 (Adapter 1) and 10.136.24.0 (adapter 2). When attached to Adapter 1, I am receiving adapter 2 ip and loopback in the addresstable entries. same is the case with Adapter1.